# Is it possible to change the iPhone microphone input while calling?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, input, call, microphone

I want to change someones voice while calling on the iPhone. Is this possible, and if it is, where do I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. There is no API for it and thus you cannot submit something like that to the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with non-jailbroken phones.

The iOS app sandbox is completely closed off from everything related to the phone, and really, there's no access to anything that low-level pretty much anywhere.